# AWS CLI list-domain-names/describe-domain returns empty even if there are domains present in the account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cmd, aws-sdk, aws-cli

We have ElasticSearch domain created in one of the AWS account.

We are trying to use AWS cli command to "describe" this domain.

```
aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name <domain-name>
```

But receiving error:

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the
>   DescribeElasticsearchDomain operation: Domain not found:

We than used list-domain command:

```
aws es list-domain-names
```

But received empty response:

> {
>       "DomainNames": [] }

We double checked account info. and credentials in .aws folder and we are pointing to correct aws account also able to view other resources in that account except ElasticSearch.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you double check your credencials in the .aws folder? Do you have a [default] credential and region configured? Suggest you also use the --profile do make sure you are using the correct credentials and region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the permission issue, It can be `profile` issue may be command run in other account but I am sure your Elastic search cluster is in a different region and you set the different region in `aws configure`

All you need to pass region to the aws command

`aws es list-domain-names --region DOMAIN_REGION`

or

`aws es list-domain-names --region us-west-1`

The exception clearly said the resources not found in the region by default which specified in `aws configure` using aws-cli.

`aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name youdomain domain_region`

Comment: Thanks,command worked for me with Profile and Region:

aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name <domain-name> --region <region> --profile <profile-name>